# How can I fix a memory leak in Gmock test when a matcher is used on a function argument that is a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, googlemock

So I have a piece of code on a big test code, not written by me, but I need to debug a leak in:

```
TEST_F(LeakChecked, PurgeNotify)
{
    AsyncManager asyncManager;
    DataIndexer indexer(*logger_, asyncManager);

    //....

    EXPECT_CALL(
        asyncManager,
        RunAsync(
            AllOf(
                EventType("DataPurged"),
                EventTime(0),
                EventJson(
                    R"({"bucket":"dropped_files","data":{"path":"c:\\foo\\test.exe"},"time":0,"type":"DataPurged"})"),
                EventCoverage()),
            _,
            0,
            0));

    //...

    Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(&asyncManager);
}
```

The fixture uses Windows' _CrtMemCheckpoint and other functions to detect memory leaks in its destructor. I had about 6 leaks there and after adding a _CrtSetBreakAlloc to break on them it turned out all of them are pointing to the aforementioned EXPECT_CALL macro.

The RunAsync is a method whose first argument is an std::shared_ptr but none of the leaks seem to indicate the pointed object is leaked, instead the allocation happens in gmock-matchers.h where it allocates a `Matcher<T>` with new.

In other threads I read that calling the VerifyAndClearExpectations should work but in my case the leak persists.

Is there anything I can do to fix, or should I just suppress the leaks?

Comment: Can you proceed by elimination? like eliminating some parts of code in the `RunAsync` function or this method belongs to a third-party library

Comment: @Landstalker RunAsync is a GMock method of a mock object. We can't touch that. The leaked memory was allocated in GMock's code.

Comment: Ok, in this case it's more complicated. You have to look at the manual side, maybe there is another function to free up resources (int addition to `VerifyAndClearExpectations`). Otherwise, try using a classic pointer (not a std :: shared_ptr), which you manage explicitly.